# Can Azure generate a certificate at the cloud side?

Tags: iis, azure, ssl, deployment, https

During the development, we didn't get the domain binding for our application, so we just use the Azure URL, something like this: xxx.cloudapp.net.

Because we would like our website use HTTPS protocol, we need to use a certificate, just follow the MSDN, we generated the self-signed pfx file using IIS Manager. Before we publish our application to cloud, we upload the pfx file to cloud by the portal page.

So my question is, is above the only way for this situation? Which I means, I need to upload the certificate to cloud manually first, then publish the application? Is there a way I don't need to to this, something like I even not rely on IIS Manager, the cloud can generate a certificate?

Comment: Won't such self-signed certificates be rejected by browsers?

Comment: @sharptooth huh yes, I just tested that locally, for cloud I have no chance to test (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22904936/get-separate-url-for-each-webrole-workerrole-of-cloudservice-in-azure). And at least the HTTPS works, maybe after the real certificate used, everything would be OK.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you would want to avoid the process of 1st uploading the certificate in the portal in order for SSL to work. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @GauravMantri exactly.

Comment: @sharptooth Do you know, how to prevent this self-signed certificate be rejected by browsers showing warning? Is it possible?

Comment: @JerryBian: Nope, that's by design. The client will validate the trust chain to ensure that it was indeed issued by someone trusted. Otherwise anyone would be able to pretend anything.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple answer to your question is No, Azure can't create a certificate for you. But you could do the same.

To elaborate further, let me explain you what's happening behind the scenes. So you have uploaded the PFX certificate in the portal and in your application configuration screen you have specified the thuumbprint of that certificate. When Azure Fabric Controller spins of the VM, it checks for this certificate thumbprint and based on that it fetches the certificate you uploaded previously and installs that certificate. Furthermore it makes changes to the IIS settings does the SSL magic. Now if you want (not sure why) but you could do the same. If we take just development environment, what you could do is write a startup task which would first create a certificate using `makecert` utility. Then you would write some IIS scripts which will do the SSL magic for IIS.

Yet another thing you could do is automate the deployment of your code using [`Azure PowerShell Cmdlets`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj156055.aspx). As a part of deployment automation, 1st thing you would do is upload the SSL certificate using [`Add-AzureCertificate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn495214.aspx) and then create a deployment of your service using [`New-AzureDeployment`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn495143.aspx).